# Keeping result data in same order as inserted

Tags: sql, average

I've data inserted into table dept like this

```
Dept  Deptname
1     '1  dept'
5     '5   dept'
10     '10 dept'
20     '20 dept'
4      '4  DEPT'
3      '3 DEPT'
```

And after matching dept from Dept table to Emp table i want to display the matched results in the same deptname order along with avg sal of dept.
Result should be like this

```
Deptname  avgsal
'1  dept'   1000
'5  dept'   1100
'10  dept'  2000
'20  dept'  1500
```

How to achieve result in same order with displaying only deptname and avg sal

Comment: ORDER BY will handle this.

Comment: Try to elaborate your question what I mean make it little clear. try to display in the form of table or show what you have done till now

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. The only way to get a guaranteed output order from a query is to write an `ORDER BY` clause on that query.

Comment: If you want the order of inserting data to be used for future references then you need to have an identity column so that you can order by.

Answer (score 0):

use order by , there is no way without using `order by` to show result any particular order

```
  order by Dept asc
```

Comment: But dept values are different order; results needed are as per dept name order along with avg sal from emp table

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
select dept.deptname, 
       (select avg(emp.sal) from emp where emp.dept = dept.dept) as avgsal
  from dept
```

By calculating average salary inside `SELECT` clause you will retain the order of data shown as you see them when you simply select from your `dept` table (and NOT ordered by `dept` or `deptname`). If I am correct, that's exactly what you want.

I hope I helped!